# Copy files from Android storage to assets folder

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

In my application I want a image gallery that will show the images that were taken from the Android camera. So, I am trying to copy files from the Android storage to the assets folder to make a image gallery.

For that I have write the following code.

```
    string sourceDriectory="";
    string targetDriectory="";
    void Start()
    {
        CopySomething( sourceDriectory, targetDriectory);
    }
static void CopySomething(string sourceDriectory, string targetDriectory)
    {
        UnityEditor.FileUtil.CopyFileOrDirectory(sourceDriectory, targetDriectory);
    }
```

In this code I am not getting how can I will set the `sourceDriectory` path and the `targetDriectory` path.

Comment: What did you mean? `android storage` to `asset folder`? In Android, you can not copy file to `asset folder`, it's a part of apk and not modifiable.

Comment: Also you can't can anything related to `UnityEditor` at runtime on any other platform than the Editor itself.

Comment: I assume `assest` was meant to be `assets`, so I have fixed that. The `Driectory` variables are all misspelled and should be `Directory`, but I doubt that is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to copy images only to show them in your app. You can just directly access the image files and display in your app.

Take a look at [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/537476/open-gallery-android.html) for how you can access images from gallery.

Comment: how can use it. means dose i have to call setImage() in start() or anything else. replay me as soon as possible

Comment: Yes, you can call `setImage()` method in start.You should call `setImage()` method whenever you want to load image from gallary.

Comment: actually i am not getting the algo of that code. dose it automatically make image frame and show  images in them. As images were seen in native image gallery? But i have try with calling setImage() in start() but nothing happened.

Comment: The algo accesses images list from gallary and sets the first image from list to `private RawImage m_image;` variable. Now you can add this `RawImage` component to an empty gameObject inside a canvas. RawImage ref  - https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-RawImage.html

Comment: it just give first image? not remaining images.

Comment: Statement `List<string> galleryImages = GetAllGalleryImagePaths();` stores all gallery image paths in `galleryImages` variable. In statement `(new WWW(galleryImages[0])).LoadImageIntoTexture(t);` change the `[0]` to any index value to access the image path. If you want to load all the images then use a `for loop` form index `0` to `galleryImages.Count` and load the textures in a `RawImage` List.